# MarkLogic Data Hub install & upgrade

Tags: marklogic

Ive been installing brand new ( empty ) Data Hub 4.1.1 so I can practice upgrade ( 4.1.1 to  4.3.2 ,  then up to 5.2.6 ).

Ive been using the quickstart instructions here https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/tutorial/4x/install/  to do the install, but wonder if I'm "cheating" and should instead be using same Gradle install method as for 5.2.x?

To  clarify - can you install 4.1.1 using the same method for 5.2.x  as described here https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.2/projects/create-project-using-gradle.html,
or do you need to follow the 4.x.x instructions only?

If we follow the 4.1.1 example, for sample data provided, it seems you initialize the project via Quickstart ( which then adds extra files etc to the local hard disk into the project directory), then you install the project *as a discrete Data Hub* into markLogic.
Is it correct to say each project is its own Data Hub?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the 5.2 instructions. The 4.x instructions are not really different, as you can see from here:

https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/project/gradle/

4.x also has scaffolding tasks. Run `./gradlew tasks`, and look for tasks starting with `hub` or `ml`.

HTH!